# How to install the debian bash-completion using homebrew?

Tags: macos, bash, homebrew, .bash-profile

I want bash to install [bash command completion](http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org) on my mac using [`brew`](http://brew.sh).

Answer (score 5):

install `bash-completion`

```
brew install bash-completion
```

Do not forget to add the following snippet to your .bash_profile:

```
if [ -f `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion ]; then 
    . `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion 
fi
```

This will include the completion commands into your interactive `bash` in Terminal.app.

To add a new completion script, just drop it into the `bash_completion.d` directory

```
cp my_completion_script `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion.d
```

Comment: Following the above steps: I am getting:
$ source ~/.bash_profile
-bash: complete: -D: invalid option
complete: usage: complete [-abcdefgjksuv] [-pr] [-o option] [-A action] [-G globpat] [-W wordlist] [-P prefix] [-S suffix] [-X filterpat] [-F function] [-C command] [name ...]
On Mac